# Adding Child to Document Class Vs Adding Child to Stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

The name of my DocumentClass is Main. 
So, what's the difference between :

```
var myClass:Main = new Main(); 
var mcInLibrary:MovieClip ; 

/////////////////////////////////////////

myClass.addChild(mcInLibrary) ;

////////  - VS - /////////////////////

myClass.stage.addChild(mcInLibrary) ;

/////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? you're asking lot of questions but rarely mark any answer as good, and this is not a good idea for the community. I just realized that this is the second answer I've given to you today :(

Comment: How does it make a difference for me.. adding child in stage or Document class.. Visually it appears the same.Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
 myClass.addChild(mcInLibrary) ;
```

you're adding the mcInLibrary to the DisplayList of myClass.

With

```
 myClass.stage.addChild(mcInLibrary) ;
```

you're adding it to the stage in which myClass is instantiated.
Every instance which is derived from DisplayObject has the property stage, which refers to the stage instance to which it is added (essentially the root of the Display list).